# Typescript "keyof typeof myObj" gives me the actual keys on "myObj", but not if it has a type "myObj: myType". How can i do both?

Tags: typescript, typeof, keyof

I want to get the actual keys of "myObj", but also ensure its type. If I add a type I no longer get the actual keys. How can i do both?

example 1

```
const myObj = {
    in01: 'Hello', 
    in02: 'World'
}
type actualKeys = keyof typeof myObj // result: "in01" | "in02" (this is what I want)
```

example 2

```
type myType = {
    [x: string]: string
}
const myObj: myType = { // I get to validate the type (what I want)
    in01: 'Hello', 
    in02: 'World'
}
type actualKeys = keyof typeof myObj // result: string | number (this is no longer the actual keys. Not what I want)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Indexable type `myType`  allows number as keys.

Therefore `keyof myType` returns `string | number`

Since you define `myObj` to be of type `myType`, `keyof typeof myObj` is the same as `keyof myType`, hence the `string | number`.

With TS 4.9 (yet to be released), you will be able to ensure the type without actually typing it using the `satisfies` keyword.

```
type myType = {
    [x: string]: string
}
const myObj = {  // ok
    in01: 'Hello', 
    in02: 'World'
} satisfies myType

const myObj2 = {  // KO
    in01: 'Hello', 
    in02: 'World'
    0: 'lala', // nope
} satisfies myType


type actualKeys = keyof typeof myObj
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20221019#code/C4TwDgpgBAtiAq5oF4oG8BQVtQNoA8AuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBdYsqujAXwwGMB7as2EAHkARgCsoqNNgD00qNwDWWHDQAMARmIByABIQANvu5aANFGXY1AJm0B1buX0ATLe1IBDYJRIAzShBIBREgMLl5%20OBFRKwl0GTkAaUELKDVNKF0DI1NzHFTqVRsM%200cXFNVtfXcqnNkoam4Qtg8vX39AuGCIUIxQSCh3TmAAV2qEiBBA1AUJ7h8oPog5gSioOoAiNPWoAB8oTYKrdaA)

Comment: Where's the "how"? This is only the "why". Hint: `satisfies`

Comment: `satisfies` isn't available yet (in stable) ;) @caTS

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't write anything about it though :x

Comment: The satisfies operator looks like a good solution to my problem :)

Comment: @Slein indeed, I updated my answer.